# Reusing style in NativeWind

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

NativeWind basically coming from tailwindcss, I was wondering if there is a way to [reuse styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-component-classes) just like in tailwindcss where you can have define a class name that will hold a set of styles and therefore you could just apply that class name to a tag directly

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .select2-dropdown {
    @apply rounded-b-lg shadow-md;
  }
  .select2-search {
    @apply border border-gray-300 rounded;
  }
  .select2-results__group {
    @apply text-lg font-bold text-gray-900;
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Did you find a way to do something like this?

Comment: Not exactly the same but I have defined styles in the my utils that I can use anywhere in the code by just calling the variables

Comment: If you have the time please write up an answer or a gist, would love to see it, as I am also trying to get something similar going. I wish they had support for CSS styles

https://github.com/marklawlor/nativewind/discussions/447

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the exact solution but the walkaround I used was to have the styles in my `Utils` file and then import them wherever I would need them.

Utils.js

```
const buttonStyle = "bg-[#fac25a] py-2 rounded-md mx-10 mt-10 mb-3";
const textInputStyle =
  "tracking-widest bg-gray-100 rounded-lg w-[80%] text-base py-2 px-1 mx-5 mb-5";
export { buttonStyle, textInputStyle };
```

In my `LoginScreen.jsx` I then import the styles from the `Utils` file and use them in the className with the template string

```
import { buttonStyle, textInputStyle } from "../Utils";

<TextInput
            className={`${textInputStyle}`}
            placeholder="Enter password"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            autoCorrect={false}
            textContentType="password"
            value={password}
            onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
 />
```

Applied on a touchable opacity

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={HandleLogin} className={`${buttonStyle}`}>
          <Text className="text-center font-semibold text-white text-lg">
            Login
          </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      grey1000: '#000000',
      grey900: '#141414',
      grey800: '#1F1F1F',
      grey700: '#333333',
      grey600: '#545454',
      grey500: '#757575',
      grey400: '#AFAFAF',
      grey300: '#CBCBCB',
      grey200: '#E2E2E2',
      grey100: '#EEEEEE',
      grey50: '#F6F6F6',
      grey0: '#FFFFFF',
      red800: '#E11900',
      blue500: '#276EF1',
    },
    fontSize: {
      title01b: ['28px', {lineHeight: '39.2px', fontWeight: '700'}],
      title01m: ['28px', {lineHeight: '33.6px', fontWeight: '500'}],
      title02b: ['24px', {lineHeight: '28.8px', fontWeight: '700'}],
      title02m: ['24px', {lineHeight: '28.8px', fontWeight: '500'}],
      title03m: ['20px', {lineHeight: '24px', fontWeight: '500'}],
      title04b: ['18px', {lineHeight: '24px', fontWeight: '700'}],
      title04m: ['18px', {lineHeight: '24px', fontWeight: '500'}],
      body01r: ['16px', {lineHeight: '25.6px', fontWeight: '400'}],
      body02sb: ['15px', {lineHeight: '24px', fontWeight: '600'}],
      body03b: ['14px', {lineHeight: '22.4px', fontWeight: '700'}],
      body03m: ['14px', {lineHeight: '22.4px', fontWeight: '500'}],
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size#providing-a-default-line-height

For text, you can set fontSize, lineHeight, letterSpacing, and fontWeight in this way.

```
  <Text className='text-title01b' />
```